# DataGridView column disappears after deleting records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datagridview

I have a Windows Forms `DataGridView` in which I display a combination of two tables.

I have a delete function which deletes a row. My problem is whenever I perform the delete function, one of the column disappears.

[image: before delete]

[image: after delete]

Below is the code for calling the tables into the datagridview

```c#
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT tblRequest.Id, usrTbl.nama, tblRequest.userId, tblRequest.leaveDays, tblRequest.leaveRequest, tblRequest.startDate, tblRequest.endDate, tblRequest.supId, tblRequest.permission FROM tblRequest CROSS JOIN usrTbl WHERE tblRequest.userId = usrTbl.Id AND tblRequest.supId='" + this.lblName.Text + "'", sc);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

The column that disappears after the delete operation is the `nama` column, which is the only `usrTbl` entity that is join with the `tblRequest`.

My T-SQL is

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblRequest] 
(
    [Id]           INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [userId]       INT  NOT NULL,
    [leaveDays]    INT  NOT NULL,
    [leaveRequest] TEXT NULL,
    [startDate]    TEXT NULL,
    [endDate]      TEXT NULL,
    [supId]        INT  NULL,
    [permission]   TEXT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),

    CONSTRAINT [FK_tblRequest_ToTable] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([userId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[usrTbl] ([Id]) 
             ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

My delete code:

```c#
string Query = "delete from tblRequest where Id='" + this.idTxt.Text + "';";

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(con);
SqlCommand sqlCom = new SqlCommand(Query, sqlCon);
```

Does anyone have any clue on what I did wrong?

Comment: for your datagridvie, after assigning the datasource try calling the `DataGridView.Refresh()` for your datagridview. also I would read up on how to construct query's using `Parameters` and read up on `SQL INJECTION` as well..

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This is wide open to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves code like this. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to delete the row in your SQL Table. So far so good, but as soon as you refresh you grid, your manual added column `nama` will disappear, because it isnt in your table on your database.

Try to add the column not in your sql statement but in your code or even in the designer. That should fix the problem.

Or as refered in the comments below my post, check this discussion to see how to create a datatable with a tableadapter to manager you SQL Data more easy.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88acfb48-b5b2-42d2-881d-5cd14eac4790/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-fill-datatable-from-sql-server?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: this could actually be done without using a Delete command if the OP would bind the original data from a select query to a DataTable then if they wanted to delete the row(s) from the datatable using the `Filtering` by means of the `DataTable.Select` method and only 1 trip to the database is performed from the select and the delete would be performed from in memory

Comment: @MethodMan Yes, that would made things a lot more easy. I can edit my post to refer to a documentation that shows how to perform that.

Comment: @Cataklysim could you elaborate on that method? I still don't understand from the article that you provided. Myb an example based on my problem? I'm not asking you to solve my problem, just direct me to the right path...

Comment: @jenan can you show us what happens after you press the delete button? Is there anything else or do you just call your delete method?

Comment: @Cataklysim the picture above that I included in this post stated shows the joined table column 'nama' disappear after I clicked the delete button. When I tried to delete the next row, it returns the error unhandled exception.